# Split button in a tool window toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx, vsix

i'm writing a visual studio 2010 extension and got a ToolWindow with a ToolWindowToolbar.

in my toolbar i want to add a split button that while pressing the button (left part) will show the 'open file' dialog, and when pressing the arrow (right part) will show a list of recently opened files.

i have tried several ways to no avail, can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see solution [in this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/b50df040-6dc7-4b6c-bd6d-5b68fc7c42a5)

Answer (score 0):

This thread from MSDN Visual Studio Extensibility Forum might help you. 
"[Bitmap icon does not appear on a SplitDropDown button in Visual Studio toolbar](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/vsx/thread/6e21e7b7-92da-4c84-b168-a3393259d565)"

Comment: yes, well... i've been there with the MenuController. it was a good start. but how do i make the button part of that controller do some command that is not in the drop down? (detailed in my original post)